# Issue while swapping in MIPS (Infinite Loop)

Tags: c, mips, infinite-loop, swap

I am new to MIPS. I am trying to swap two elements in MIPS using the parameter and return value passing mechanism.

This is the C Code:

```
swap(int *a, int *b)
    {
      int temp;
      temp = *a;
      *a = *b;
      *b = temp;
    }
```

My MIPS code:

```
.data
aa: .word 1
bb: .word 2 
    .text

main:   la $a0, aa 
        la $a1, bb
        jal swap
    
swap: 
    lw $t0,($a0)
    lw $t1,($a1)
    sw $t1,($a0)
    sw $t0,($a1) 
    jr $ra
```

I am getting an `Infinite Loop Detected` error.

When I have use `syscall` -> `Unsupported or Invalid Instruction` I'm getting an error like this.

Any solution?

Comment: Try single stepping.  Take a look at what happens when `swap` returns to `main`...  Where do we expect `main`  to resume after call to `swap`?  What does main do after calling `swap`?

Comment: This works for me if I exit the program with `li $v0, 10` and `syscall` after `jal swap`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is little tricky.

When you call the function, $ra includes the address of the line after  `jal swap` .

Which line is this?! you guess right, the line of  `swap:` , I offer to write code that ends the program, between `jal swap` and `swap:`.

`li $v0,10 # $v0 = 10
syscall    # ends the program`

Comment: I am still getting this error `Unsupported or invalid instruction : syscall` when I run the code. May I know what software you use to run MIPS Program?